# replace execution thread with new thread java

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrent-programming

I want to know how to replace current thread of execution with a new thread object in Java. Some more context, the new thread will be fetched from a concurrent hashmap of with unique key and value as thread objects . Unique key might be obtained from the current thread of execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really "replace" the current thread with another thread, you can just add another thread and terminate the fist one. I don't know if you consider that replacing.

If you show us some code demonstrating how your "current" thread is being started and approximately what it's doing, then we might be able to give you some more pointers on how to either block the current thread (thus forcing it not to work) or to terminate that thread all-together (which are pretty much your two major options).